# Ionic, show facebook page posts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, facebook, ionic-framework

I´m developing a new **Ionic App** and my customer wants to show their Facebook page post inside the app (please, don´t ask me why).

I just addes the regular FB plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) and works fine in the Ionic server, but it doesnt works when i run the App. I

Looks like Ionic can´t handle the FP frame, but i´m not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you debug it? you can easily debug ionic/cordova apps by connecting your phone and using chrome://inspect

Comment: Hi, just did it (nice Chrome feature by the way, really usefull), but i´m not getting any errors or warnings

Comment: then i assume you are right about the iframe. but why use the page plugin anyway? why not use the feed endpoint and read the posts with the api? probably fits better for an app.